# Configuring postgresql in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on a project with a friend. I cloned the application from bitbucket. Everything was fine except postgresql (v9.3.7) . It keeps giving me the following message.

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
```

I have created a superuser as well as all the databases. The designated users and the list of all the databases is given below.

```
ubuntu=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 divjot    | Superuser                                      | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 ubuntu    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB              | {}

 List of databases
      Name       |  Owner   | Encoding  | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 app_development | ubuntu   | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
 app_production  | ubuntu   | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
 app_test        | ubuntu   | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
 postgres        | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | 
 template0       | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1       | postgres | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |           |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 ubuntu          | ubuntu   | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     |
```

I have always struggled with postgresql configuration in rails. I follow the documentation completely, however, every time I try to clone application or move the code, I always run into problems. I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: looks like user`ubuntu` is not allowed to log in. do check your pg_hba.conf file.

Comment: @wildplasser, what is the command to get access to the files.

Comment: What version? Part of the issue (IME) is that version matters.

Comment: @gene, I am running version psql (9.3.7)

Comment: Add `database.yaml` and ENV['DATABASE_URL'] ` setting, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on pgsql. But I've successfully set up pg/rails in several versions and environments.  Here's what I suggest.

- Find the `pg_hba.conf` file. Since you are apparently using Ubuntu, try

  `cd /`
  `find . -name pg_hba.conf -print 2> /dev/null`

This will search your whole disk, which will take a while. But eventually it will provide the path. If it produces more than one, you'll have to resolve which one is correct.

If you know where PG is installed, `cd` there instead of root.

Now

- Verify the auth method for user `ubuntu` is `password` or maybe `md5`. [Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) is the relevant docs page. If you're interested only in local development, you can  change `password` to `trust`.  But if this is for production, that's a bad idea.
- While logged into the `pg` command line, run 
  `ALTER USER ubuntu PASSWORD 'newpassword';`
  to ensure the password is what you think it is.
- You should post `database.yaml` or `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` settings. In general, `database.yaml` needs to match precisely what pg expects.

For example:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: ubuntu
  password: <your password>
  allow_concurrency: true
```

Caveat: Don't commit production passwords to your repos or even dev passwords if you don't totally control the repo.

Comment: It took me some time to find and edit the file. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Highly appreciate it, Thanks!!